# What could have happened to the two traveler wires in previously working three way light?

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch

The high-hat lights (retrofitted with LEDs) in kitchen stopped working. They were controlled by two three-way light switches, one a dimmer. I played around with different configurations of the switches (including dimmer set to maximum), but lights never came on. I figured one of the switches failed. Replaced the non-dimmer switch first because it's cheaper to no avail. Replaced the dimmer and still no luck.

I figured maybe I somehow wired wrong and so pulled both switches and started testing. Identifying the common, the traveler wires, etc. I believe I had wired the new switches correctly. I also tried with no dimmer at all, just two, regular three-way switches, and the lights still didn't work.

Anyway, so a couple tests I've done:

1. I took some spare lamp cord and connected common from one switch to the common of the other. Flipped the breaker back on, and the lights came on. So the lights work and I've correctly identified the common.
2. Using the lamp cord and a DMM, I measured the resistance between the red traveler wire of one switch to that of the other junction box. The DMM reports out-of range, indicating they are not connected! Same for the black traveler wire. If one wire went bad, that's one thing, but what are the chances both got disconnected?
3. By accident, I measured the resistance from black traveler wire to red at the same junction box. It keeps moving around between 30 and 1000 Ohms. Similar behavior at the other junction box. This is with the breaker still off. Two wires in the same Romex connected together? Could the Romex inside the wall have been severed in such a way to short the red to black on both sides of the cut in such a way that the short is unreliable (hence the variation in resistance)?

I'm left wondering:

1. There's been no recent work or change to our house. What could have happened to the traveler wires?
2. It seems crystal clear, but am I somehow missing something about what the problem is?
3. If indeed, the traveler wires are severed/shorted/unreliable, how does one fix it?
4. A commenter suggested that rodents may have eaten the wires. But I think things are wired as in this picture: ~[circuit diagram](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.askmediy.com%2Fhow-to-wire-a-three-way-switch-to-a-existing-single-pole-light-switch-circuit%2F&psig=AOvVaw28g1Qu5o-SL4VBC17Toste&ust=1599423730402000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCOjKoOzr0usCFQAAAAAdAAAAABA-)
   and I think the fact that the lights worked when I directly connected the two common wires suggests that the neutral (white) wire in the Romex with the two traveler wires is indeed continuous. I would test directly, but the white is capped along with other wires behind other switches (this holds for each of the junction boxes). Can someone confirm/deny this line of thinking?

Comment: Can you tell if the travelers run directly from one switch location to the other, or if there are junction boxes in the middle?

Comment: I don't see anyway to tell. However, the two switches are only about ten feet away from each other with no other switches in between them, and so I would doubt there are any boxes in between.

Comment: So you changed the wires on a working system because the LED’s did not work! Go back to regular lighting and Get it working again then replace the electronic dimmer with one that Supports the LED’s. Then change back to the LED’s would be my advice.

Comment: I haven't changed any wires. The LEDs have been in the lights (and working) for a few years now. After the new dimmer didn't work, I tried a regular, three-way rocker switch (w/o dimmer). And so I don't think LEDs or dimmer have any relevance to the problem. I just mention in case I'm missing something.

Comment: I don't know where you are but I've seen (and personally experienced) rodent damage to wires in the wall on more than one occasion. The little buggers get up there and chew on the cables until they either short out or open up.   I had a true short that was tripping a breaker with no load on the circuit. Found dead mice (electrocuted) in the wall when I opened it up.   I don't care how clean your house is, anybody can get rodents and have them do damage.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Yeah, I thought maybe, but no evidence of rodents (noise, droppings). And also wouldn't they have eaten through the neutral/white wire as well? (I added a question about this above). Also, what's the fix? Hire an electrician to open up the wall?

Comment: Failures in cables installed for years is extremely rare.  Usually something causes it, where it be a nail or screw driven in for hanging something and just happened to hit the cable (again ,very unlikely) or rodent damage, or????  You don't need an electrician to open up a wall, but admittedly it's hard to know where to open it up. Sometimes wiring a house electricians go "up and over" meaning up the stud across the joists and down the other stud, other times they just go through the studs to save wire. If you have attic access I'd check to see if the 3way cable is there. (continued...)

Comment: If so, check for rodent damage there and even possibly use a camera probe to stick down between the studs (assuming it's not an insulated wall) to check for damage there. You may need to drill a small hole if the hole with the cables in the top plate is sealed. Take care when doing this, there may be cables stapled under the top plate.

Comment: What makes you believe black and red are your travelers?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Each switch had a gray, black, red, and copper wire and so presumably the travelers are two of these three because the bare copper wire is clear. As to why I believe the travelers to be red/black: (1) one of the junctions has a piece of the Romex covering around the red and black with "high hats" written on them and were connected to the two brass screws on the original switch, (2) that connecting the gray wires directly powers the lights suggest they are the hot wires and hence that red/black are travelers by elimination (3) the gray in one junction box was hot.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson This is first floor with a second floor on top, and so no attic access. I do have one of those USB cameras on a wire, but would definitely need to drill a hole. However, the rules of engagement from the spouse probably preclude any drilling :) before handing off to a professional.

Comment: Called an electrician who has yet to get back to me! In the meantime, I wired the dimmer (which is closest on the circuit to the lights) so that it controls the lights, and simply capped the travelers and the hot wire on the other switch, which now does nothing. And so we have one switch to use the kitchen lights, and there's no voltage on  any of the apparently damaged Romex between the two switches. So I think this should be safe, just not as functional as before.